# Issue with react-table in rendering and css import

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have component which I am rendering in parent component. But its not working and giving me an error

> react.createelement type is invalid expected a string but got undefined

I have a data in state object which is a array of objects.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
//import "react-table/react-table.css";


class CustomerTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableData: this.props.Data,
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.state.tableData", this.state.tableData);
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Customer ID",
        accessor: "CUSTOMER_ID",
      },
      {
        Header: "Customer Name",
        accessor: "NAME",
      },
      {
        Header: "Customer Type",
        accessor: "TYPE",
      },
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.tableData}>
        </ReactTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomerTable;
```

Another issue is that if I uncomment css import line I am getting an error

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-table/react-table.css'

I checked in package.json and its verion is  "react-table": "^7.0.4". But I cant see react-table.css file in node_module. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React table 7x is [entirely different](https://medium.com/@tannerlinsley/why-i-wrote-react-table-and-the-problems-it-has-solved-for-nozzle-others-445c4e93d4a8#.axza4ixba) from the previous version. Your code looks like react table version 6.

You need to install [react-table-6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6)

```
npm i react-table-6
```

or

```
yarn add react-table-6
```

After installing you need to import react table like this

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table-6';
import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';
```

After that your code should work. Try it.

Regarding your first issue, state might not have the data in the initial render.

try replacing

```
<ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.tableData}>
```

with

```
<ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.tableData || []}>
```

Comment: I also want to add one extra column which will have  button for every row. How can I do that. Any help please.

Comment: @Nilesh Its possible using custom cell render - Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6/examples/cell-renderers?file=/src/index.js:796-1008  and other examples here https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#codesandbox-examples

Comment: I had the same problem and tried this solution.  Now I'm getting the following error: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-table-v6'"  I took out the "v" in both references and now it is working.

Comment: @user3217883 Thanks for pointing out, `v` is not required. Answer updated.